# orientation in ios ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipod

I have an Ipad application which support in "landscape" mode now i want this to support for both "landscape and portrait" this project is made with "xib" files

i used some delegates but i did not get solution what i have to do 
i use this code

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    //The device has already rotated, that's why this method is being called.
    UIInterfaceOrientation toOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    //fixes orientation mismatch (between UIDeviceOrientation and UIInterfaceOrientation)
    if (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) toOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    else if (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) toOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

    UIInterfaceOrientation fromOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toOrientation duration:0.0];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toOrientation duration:[context transitionDuration]];
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromOrientation];
    }];

}


-(void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{

    NSLog(@"Transition");
}
```

Comment: any other methods i have to wright or any thing i have to change help me

Comment: any help will be appreciated and upvoted

Comment: read this http://goo.gl/Y3cyps, here you'll find answers.

Comment: After you study the solutions and documentations, maybe you can post an answer  to your question with an example of how you fixed it, to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add UISupportedInterfaceOrientation key with list of [orientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10) (you can make it with xCode UI in the target's General settings).
Also, if you need different orientations on different view controllers, you can override method

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

And you should read this [adaptive interface](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/), because in ios 8, orientation changing means  resizing of view.

Comment: i have some labels images views in the screen it must adjust as per the orientation please provide me example code for this

Comment: Sorry, but code rely on goals. But I think, because you are using xib files, you should use autolayout in xib. Autolayout in xib is very like to autolayout in storyboard, you can view it here http://goo.gl/wxyjwo . If you want use autolayout from code, you should see this library, it is very simple to use http://goo.gl/eMNij0

Comment: And read this http://goo.gl/q00caS, to understand how create autolayout in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: yes am using xib files and i have some views buttons labels in that xib it must be adjust with orientation but it is not adjusting

Comment: create new clear project, open created Main.storyboard. Add some labels and buttons, add constrains. Go to target General settings, check supported device orientations. Try rotate your device/simulator.

Comment: is this not possible in xib i cannot create new one it is a big project

Comment: i have to do this in xib files cannot go to storyboards

Comment: see this vide http://goo.gl/2YEzJF, it about autolayout in xib. To use autolayout in xib you should use xCode with version >= 4.0

What's happened if you rotate device?

Comment: if i rotate my device/simulator it is working but size of the views of buttons scrollview labels every thing is as landscape only do i want to wright code or use auto layouts

Comment: yes same as the video you sent that is the problem hope that video will help

Comment: It means that, you've configured wrong constraints in your xib. Layout in rotation needs code lines in small set of cases. If you use xib, you should to try make layout with constraints.

Comment: Yes you can configure constraints in code by using pure NSLayoutConstraints or some wrapper (KeepLayout).

Comment: you have example ? and this have to be done for view or all components in the view  ?

Comment: To create autolayout from code I use KeepLayout, I've appended link to this library (project on Github), you can find code example in one of example application attached to this project.

Comment: please provide me the link

Comment: Example of pure Autolayout from code: http://goo.gl/gJPDvg
KeepLayout library: http://goo.gl/eMNij0

Comment: Okay thank you i will try thanks for your support Giving you upvote

Comment: You should read links I've appended, because, without knowledges about bases of autolayout you can't understand what's happened if you rotate your device.

Comment: the above links wright there are many links please give me again

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What's happened with links? Now I try theirs, and theirs work right.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to track the screen size initially and with orientation changes in Swift on iOS 8.

I would drop the trait collection delegate method, if you're just beginning.  Programmatically working with constraints and transitions at *that* level is very involved and tricky. Some of it is evolving and/or not well documented, and things happen with constraint transitions behind the scenes that are difficult to figure out.  You probably don't need to mess with things like that for awhile.

If you have to adjust constraint programmatically at all, to start, in general it is easier to do the layout in Interface builder, with constraints, and reduce the problem to making minor adjustments to the fewest number of constraints possible from the code, where you access the specific constraints via IBOutlet, and modify their .constant property (rather than remove/replace constraints, which is very difficult to get right).

If you're just getting started at this point in the iOS history, I think Swift is a better way to go than Objective C ( I've done plenty of Objective C programming) Swift is the future with Apple, and has some nice powerful features while getting around some problems and challenges in Objective C.  And it offers many conveniences.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        adjustViewLayout(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size)
    }

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        adjustViewLayout(size)
    }

    func adjustViewLayout(size: CGSize) {
        var width = CGSize.width
        var height = CGSize.height

         /* this method will be called when the view is
            about to appear and whenever the orientation
            changes. Adjust what you need to here based
            on the incoming width and height

            you can infer whether the screen is in
            landscape or portrait by which dimension
            is larger.  Or use a switch statement
            to check for specific screen sizes
            and orientations.  Though it may
            be incomplete knowledge of layout or 
            a failure of design if you need to do that */

     }
```

Comment: can you make it for Objective-C and i have some labels images views in the screen it must adjust as per the orientation please provide me example code for this

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html

Comment: A cool thing in swift is you could make a switch statement: switch(size.width, size.height) { case (480, 320): ... } and so on.